# Why isn't my exception caught

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am calling a function which comes from a static library, it threw nlopt exception, so I used the following code to locate the exception.

```
    try
    {
        reg_info("Before GP");
        omp_set_num_threads(1);
        GP predictor(train_in, train_out);
        predictor.set_noise_lower_bound(1e-3);
        reg_info("Before Train");
        predictor.train();
        reg_info("After Train");
        reg_info("Before Predict");
        predictor.predict(pred_in, pred_y, pred_s2);
        reg_info("After Predict");
        reg_info("After GP");
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        reg_info("Exception");
    }
```

But I got the following output message:

```
 Info  : Before GP
 Info  : Before Train
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'nlopt::forced_stop'
  what():  nlopt forced stop
```

It seems that the `predictor.train();` threw the exception, but why didn't it caught by `catch(...)`? shouldn't it catch everything?

It looked at the source code of `GP::train()`, it did throw an `nlopt::forced_stop()` exception that is not properly caught, but still, I don't understand why the `catch(...)` didn't catch it successfully.

Comment: Is one of the destructors throwing when the stack is being unwound from the first exception being thrown?

Comment: Perhaps the exception is being thrown in another thread.

Comment: Also check if there are any `noexcept` specifiers on a method called in that `try{}` block

Comment: Where is the [MCVE] you've been debugging with? And a stack trace?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I can't give you an example, I've said in the description that the `GP`  comes from a compiled static library.

Comment: @Curious , I checked the header file, the `GP::train()` method doesn't have `noexcept`, but the `GP::predict()` has `noexcept`

Comment: All sorts of possible reasons.  Could be an exception is being thrown and, in the process of stack unwinding, the destructor of an object throws a second exception.   Possibly an exception is being thrown by a function, called by `GP::train()`, that is `noexcept`.  Those are just two of many possibilities that result in `std::terminate()` being called.  If you didn't write the offending function, you'll need to read any documentation you have for it.

Comment: @Peter If it is not possible to change the source code of `GP::train()`, how could I just get around this problem?

Comment: A [MCVE] is not optional. If you can't see the code then neither can we. Did you consider asking the author of the library?

Comment: @Alaya - first read the documentation for the `GP` class, and ensure you are setting up the object correctly.   If that doesn't fix the problem, you'll need to submit a bug report to the author of the class.   I suppose you could patch the library containing that class, or even patch your executable after linking, if you really want (ummm!!) an adventure - that requires detailed knowledge of how object files and executables are organised on your target system.

Comment: Is it possible that predictor.train() affected your logging mechanism? It would explain why reg_info() stopped working inside of your catch block.

Answer (score 2):

> shouldn't it catch everything?

Only if the handler is reached. There are situations where an exception can not be caught and `std::terminate` is called instead.

> [except.throw]/7 If the exception handling mechanism, after completing the initialization of the exception object but before
>   the activation of a handler for the exception, calls a function that exits via an exception, std::terminate
>   is called
>
> [except.ctor]/1 As control passes from the point where an exception is thrown to a handler, destructors are invoked by a
>   process, specified in this section, called stack unwinding. If a destructor directly invoked by stack unwind-
>   ing exits with an exception, std::terminate is called (15.5.1). [ Note: Consequently, destructors should
>   generally catch exceptions and not let them propagate out of the destructor. — end note ]